# PostBuildEvent Create Directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cmd, post-build-event

I'm trying to create a folder named Design in the build output folder using th following commandline in the PostBuildEvent in visual studio

```
mkdir $(TargetDir)Design  ....Runs Successfully but folder is not created
mkdir "$(TargetDir)Design" ....Runs Successfully but folder is not created
MD $(TargetDir)Design  ....Runs Successfully but folder is not created
MD "$(TargetDir)Design"  ....Runs Successfully but folder is not created
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What's the value of your `TargetDir` ?

Comment: Its the relative path of the output saved in the buildserver for example \\build\Sol Build\Build_1120943.7

Comment: Your syntax looks good. Can you try adding an `echo` statement after your `mkdir` command as a sanity check to be sure that the computed path is where you think it is?

Comment: When you say "Run successfully" what do you mean? I explain, you see the compiler runs and that it compiles right, but how you can prove that the postbuild event is run? Do you set "Run Allways" on the "Run Post-Build event" combo?

Comment: I made it to run on successful build. The postbuildevent is running because there are other commandlines that deletes some files and rename some folders. But the problem is creating a new folder.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
if not exist DirToCreate mkdir DirToCreate
```

Comment: if possible, please try to elaborate your answer with some explanations, etc.

Comment: This is an example that you enter in the "Post Build Events" dialog in the project settings.  Substitute your directory of choice for DirToCreate.

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me (where Design is the folder you want to create):

```
mkdir $(TargetDir)\Design
```

If you want to check for existence first:

```
if not exist $(TargetDir)\Design mkdir $(TargetDir)\Design
```

Comment: The Directory Path should be enclosed in Double Quotes as below:

if not exist "$(TargetDir)\Design" mkdir "$(TargetDir)\Design"

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the two previous answers, you could use a variable like this :

```
SET path=$(TargetDir)\Design
if not exist "%path%" mkdir "%path%"
```

That way, you'll avoid any duplication. (Tested with VS2019)

Comment: Even so many years after the question is posted this correct answer is still very useful! I apply it in Visual Studio 2022; add these two lines of code in the Post-build event and the directory is created in the output (target) directory.